# MVVM Model-property not set when command is executed from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I execute a command on my ViewModel from a TextBox-KeyUp event. The problem I'm facing is that text from the TextBox which binds to a property on the ViewModel, is (still) null when the command is executed.

ViewModel:

```
private string _myText;
public string MyText
{
    get { return _myText; }
    set 
    {
        _myText = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyText");
    }
}

// ... ICommand stuff here

private object HandleMyCommand(object param)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyText); // at this point MyText --> 'old' value, e.g. null
    return null;
}}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPannel>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbTest" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Click" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</StackPannel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (btnTest.Command.CanExecute(null))
        {
            btnTest.Command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The binding and command both work. When executing the command the normal way, using the button, the property is set nicely.

Am I not doing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` as by default `MyText` will be updated on lost focus:

```
Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

also, not related to your problem, but you can create `InputBinding` for `TextBox` to execute some `Command` when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbTest" Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I really like the InputBinding suggestion. Using MVVM I rather not do the commandexecution from code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the binding of the text property to:

```
Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```